# Using a pretrained flair model with classic word embeddings

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

I have experimented with flair models and they give really good performance. However, due to them using contextual embeddings they are incredibly slow. I want to use them with classic word embeddings instead.

The code given in the documentation is:

```
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger

# load tagger
tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-english")

# make example sentence
sentence = Sentence("George Washington went to Washington")

# predict NER tags
tagger.predict(sentence)

# print sentence
print(sentence)

# print predicted NER spans
print('The following NER tags are found:')
# iterate over entities and print
for entity in sentence.get_spans('ner'):
    print(entity)
```

How can I alter this code to use classic word embeddings for NER instead?

Answer (score 0):

First, incredibly slow is of course dependant on the compute power you are throwing at your problem, the exact models you tried, and of course the type of data the models are processing. So, as a small disclaimer, if the compute and the data are causing a bottleneck now, smaller and simpler models may still perform slow in your case.

That being said, [here](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_4_ELMO_BERT_FLAIR_EMBEDDING.md) you can see a list of all the embeddings that are supported within `flair`. Note that ["classic" `WordEmbeddings`](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/embeddings/CLASSIC_WORD_EMBEDDINGS.md) are also part of the models that you can choose from.

In your case, you could choose any of the embeddings presented on that page, for instance the FastText embeddings for English, and then use the produced representations in a downstream NER task. Within `flair`, you could check out the `SequenceTagger`. [Here](https://huggingface.co/flair/ner-english) is a great page to see how this is implemented in HuggingFace, with a training example.